# Using IN or JOIN or EXISTS CLAUSE

Tags: oracle

I have a query written using the IN Clause. I feel if there lots of records, the performance might get impacted using IN Clause.

I tried to use JOIN and EXISTS clause to write the same query written using IN CLAUSE. However, it is not working and giving results as desired.

Below is the snippet of query written with IN clause.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM TABLE2 WHERE my_date IN (Select max(my_date) from TABLE2)) ORDER BY id;
```

I tried the below query by using EXISTS clause but it is not working:

```
Select * from TABLE1 t1 where exists
(
Select 1 from TABLE2 t2 
where exists 
(
Select max(my_date) from TABLE2 t3
where t2.my_date = t3.my_date)
where t1.id = t2.id) order by t1.id;
```

Could anyone suggest how to achieve the result using EXISTS and JOINS ?

Note: my_date cited in the above example is a DateTime(Timestamp) field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `IN` clause query is perfect.

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLE1
  WHERE id IN
   (
    SELECT id FROM TABLE2
    WHERE my_date = (Select max(my_date) from TABLE2)
   ) 
 ORDER BY id;
```

If you want an `EXISTS`

```
 WITH MY_TABLE2 AS
 (
    SELECT id FROM TABLE2
    WHERE my_date = (Select max(my_date) from TABLE2)
 )
 SELECT * FROM TABLE1 T1
 WHERE EXISTS
 ( 
    SELECT 'X' FROM MY_TABLE2  T2
    WHERE T1.id = T2.id
 )
 ORDER BY id;
```

If every id in table1 has only one id in table2, you can opt for `JOIN`,
Because `EXISTS` and `IN` would supress the duplicate ids.

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLE1 T1
 INNER JOIN ( 
               SELECT id FROM TABLE2
               WHERE my_date = (Select max(my_date) from TABLE2)
            ) T2
    ON (T1.id = T2.id)
 ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: With the JOIN approach you suggested, I will get duplicate records. Guess I will need to use distinct then.

Comment: If i use EXISTS clause, do i need to go for with ? I do not want to create any temporary table.

Comment: Yes I mentioned abt the duplicates too wrt to `JOIN`. `EXISTS` I used a CTE to make sure, we query the table only once. Else it may end up in nested loop, tht might hinder performance. The temporary table you mean is already done using CTE.(WITH clause)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I'm not in a position to test this at the mo but, what about:

```
select * 
  from table1 t1
  where exists (
    select *
      from table2 t2
      where t1.id = t2.id 
        and t2.my_date = (select max(my_date) from table2 t3)
)
```

See also details on the differences between in and exists (in Oracle). You can start here: [Oracle IN vs Exists differences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12896079/758831)

Answer (score 0):

Do you **feel** there is a performance impact or have you **observed** a performance impact?

Any recent Oracle optimizer should be able to handle your IN query just fine. Check your `EXPLAIN PLAN` and see if anything triggers an expensive operation like a full table scan. That is a starting point for rewriting the query or maybe adding an index to your table.

Answer (score 0):

Don't rewrite queries that already work, and are performing well, just because you "feel" they might be impacted. Measure and test.

If you are running modern Oracle (10.2 or later) then you should use a simple rule of thumb.

1. Treat 'IN()' vs 'EXISTS()' as equivalent in performance, Oracle itself does
2. Write the clearest, correct query for the scenario
3. Keep your db statistics up to date
4. Analyze the execution plan

Old articles, even Ask Tom threads from 2003, discussing Oracle 7, 8 or 9, and how IN() is slower, or EXISTS() produces for each and all the rest of the old rule based optimizer shortcomings are out of date. Tom Kyte acknowledged this and wrote several articles later on the subject, but unfortunately his old Ask Tom archives do a bit of damage to the reputation of IN() or the capability of Oracle in general.

IN == EXISTS.  Oracle's optimizer will transform between the two and choose similar plans in most every scenario I've tested in the past half decade.